# how to do paging inside the datalist control

Tags: asp.net

i need  to  do paging for a datalist  control. i will be  displaying (6 columns* 5  rows).  so once the record  is  exceed  it  should  go to next page
can  any one  give the  code  how  tio implement this  one.  as  we  dnt hvae    a  built in paging for   datalist control
  thank  you

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [RepeatColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx) property of the DataList control, paging can be done in classical way. :

```
DataList1.RepeatColumns = 6;
DataList1.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
```

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: sorry but what you understand from this line : (6 columns* 5 rows)

Comment: @Canavar, since he is currently showing (6 column * 5 rows = 30 Records), if record exceed then he need paging

Answer (score -1):

For Datalist Paging use PagedDataSource, PagedDataSource is used to provide a paging facility to data-bound controls such as DataList, Repeater, DataGrid, GridView,  DetailsView and FormView that allow it to perform paging.
For Example
Create SQL Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_category](
[catid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[categoryname] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_category] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[catid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =  OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Default.aspx Page contain

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("categoryname") %>'></asp:Label>                        

         </ItemTemplate>                                             
    </asp:DataList>
     <asp:label id="lblCurrentPage" runat="server"></asp:label>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnPrev" 
Runat="server" onclick="lbtnPrev_Click">Prev</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnNext" 
Runat="server" onclick="lbtnNext_Click">Next</asp:LinkButton>
```

Next Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ItemsGet();
}

  private void ItemsGet()
{

    string qry = "select catid, categoryname from tbl_category";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(a.dbConnection());
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);       
    PagedDataSource pgsrc = new PagedDataSource();
    pgsrc.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    pgsrc.AllowPaging = true;
    pgsrc.PageSize = 3;
    pgsrc.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;      
    DataList1.DataSource = pgsrc;
    DataList1.DataBind();
    lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page: " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of "  + pgsrc.PageCount.ToString();      

}
public int CurrentPage
{
    get
    {
        // look for current page in ViewState
        object o = this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"];
        if (o == null)
            return 0; // default page index of 0
        else
            return (int)o;
    }

    set
    {
        this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"] = value;
    }
}
protected void lbtnPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set viewstate variable to the previous page
    CurrentPage -= 1;
    // Reload control
    ItemsGet();
}
protected void lbtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set viewstate variable to the next page
    CurrentPage += 1;
    // Reload control
    ItemsGet();
}
```